# Why does K3b fail to write Data DVDs in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, burning, k3b

I am not yet very familiar with Ubuntu, having only recently switched to the  14.04 LTS version from Windows. For the past few days I have been trying to burn a few movie files to make a data DVD with K3b, without success. With a blank DVD+RW, it first says "Preformatting rewritable disk", and then "Erasing failed", and ejects the disk. I then tried to burn an ordinary blank DVD. It started to "Flush cache" (what does this mean?), but this never got under way, let alone completed.

I need help from experienced people. Is K3b not yet fully compatible with Ubuntu 14.04? Or do I have to tweak some settings of K3b? I would also appreciate hearing from anyone facing similar problems with K3b. Incidentally, I  also tried Brasero. It showed "Success" but in actual fact there was nothing written on the disks.

Comment: I may add the following to the above.

Comment: Sorry, the previous incomplete comment got posted by an accidental error. I wanted to add that I again tried with the same DVD RW. With K3b it was not even detected. Brasero detected it and apparently wrote till the end but then came out with the message "an unknown error". Of course, by then the RW disc may have already been ruined in the earlier attempts.

Comment: I have similiar problem, and apparently my DVD Burner on this laptop, broken. Check your hardware.

Comment: No, it can't be that because the burner works on Windows. In your case did K3b work after changing the hardware?

Comment: Okay, in my case, I have no new hardware. But my hardware was broken, though.

Comment: it could be [cdrkit](http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/cdrecord.html), it's best to use [cdrtools](https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/ubuntu/cdrtools), k3b uses them as back-end @user255726